# Xcode: Signing for "gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp" requires a development team

Tags: xcode, grpc, ios13, xcode11

When you compile Xcode for Mac app or other iOS, you may see below error

> Signing for "gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.

My Xcode version: 11.2.1
Mac OS: 10.15.1

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It is easy to fix, follow my steps:

- In Xcode, Choose **Pods** on your left

[image]

- Go to Signing & Capabilities, choose **gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp**

[image]

- Choose **Team**

[image: Open Team]

- Restart Xcode or clean Xcode with short cut: *Command + Shift + k*

Comment: I can't find this for my Swift iOS app project

Comment: I found it eventually. Apple keeps moving things around in different versions of XCode :) I clicked on the project name in the address bar, which brought up a context menu and I went to "Edit Schemes".

Comment: This works on XCode 14 released in September 2022.

Comment: Why do you have to do this in the first place?

Comment: after full day of trying to find a solution finally this worked for me. Pay attention that you should select ALL under Signing & Capabilities when selecting the team. Otherwise it won't work

Comment: After restarting XCode, you should delete pod files and run `pod install` if the error remains.

Comment: Why do we need to sign a cocoapod anyways?

Comment: In my case, I still have to select a team for this file again, even after deleting pod files and running pod install. Any ideas what is causing this or how I can make it keep the selected team? Otherwise I always run in this error all the time.

Comment: @Finn same for me

Comment: @Finn same for me, a disrupt the build flow. Would love to find a solution.

Comment: I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72561696/xcode-14-needs-selected-development-team-for-pod-bundles

which suggests to modify pod file and set dev team to your team id. The specific solution depends on your platform though, my case firebase generates the pod file so a bit trickier.