# Xcode 14 needs selected Development Team for Pod Bundles

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image: XCode image indicating error for lack of required development team]

Both projects won't build with the Xcode 14 beta because of no selected Development Team. Both times it's the target with the blue lego icon (Bundles I suppose?)

It seems that in earlier versions of Xcode the Team also wasn't set but it hasn't lead to a build error.

Would it be wrong to select my own development team here?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This `post_install` script in podfile fixed it. As it seems setting the own developer team is necessary. Replace Your Team ID with the TeamID of your project.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings["DEVELOPMENT_TEAM"] = "Your Team ID"
         end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: just to say this worked for me and didn't break anything for building with Xcode 13

Comment: Also don't forget to disable `bitcode` setting in XCode build settings if enabled.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. thanks for the help. Not sure why every XCODE update has to break the build process

Comment: You can also put `config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'`, which I prefer because I use multiple team ID's for each app.

Comment: This is just a workaround, not a fix. In fact you may have multiple targets with different team IDs.

Comment: Ref https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11402

Comment: @JulianK Is it any way to set Code Signing Allowed to "False" or "no" from the library project instead if writing that script in podfile? (When I'm the owner of the sdk/library which asks for select a development team) Thanks.

Comment: Cocoapods 1.12.0 now adds `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED = 'NO'` without needing to modify your Podfile.

Answer (score 106):

I prefer the below code so you not need to sign every individual package and it is easy when you are using multiple signing teams.

```
post_install do |installer|

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end

  end
```

Comment: Got the problem while building a release after upgrading from Xcode 13 to Xcode 14. This solution worked for me.

Comment: yes same problem for me after updating the xcode.

Comment: Is there any downside using this?

Comment: @theMoonlitKnight --  No

Comment: I had to run `pod install` after modifying. Worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

In case there is someone needs to know the correct structure of the **PodFile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '12.0'


target 'APPTarget' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!
       
    # Your packages goes here

end
 
# Disable signing for pods
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
         end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was flutter.h not found, google sign in (as above) and webview. This few lines worked if it helps :

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["DEVELOPMENT_TEAM"] = "developer code"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're experiencing errors with a particular framework, you can manually replace the problematic Pods. To do so, add the debug and release file "CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED = NO" in the Support Files section located below.
[This is sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KXp7.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you have different signing certificates for different schemes and don't need the pods signed, you can leave the Team in Xcode to **none** with the **Automatically manage signing** checked by default.

Then add the following *config.build_settings*... lines to the post_install step in your Pod file, example:

```perl
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            
            # disable code signing for pods
            config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
        end
    end
end
```