# Signing error for specific targets after Xcode 14 beta update in pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

As you can see in the picture below, there are three types of targets available in pods.

[image: Targets]

What does each one of those types mean?

Recently I upgraded to `Xcode 14 Beta`, and I had to use signing for blue-colored ones.

Also, as I have bitcode enabled in my project, I had to manually enable bit code for those targets.

None of which was required in `Xcode 13.4.1`.

I read [Xcode 14 releasenotes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes) but failed to get a proper understanding of these changes.

Comment: Please, check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72600584/6013998

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the internals, but I did face the problem of manually enabling bitcode for all my pods targets. I am using the snippet below to automate that.

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end
```